# The picture in the braintree ad is the wrong product

Tags: bug, advertising

Currently on the site the following ad is running:

[image]

The product shown is not a Oculus Rift, it is a [Samsung GearVR](https://www.oculus.com/gear-vr/), a similar product also made by Oculus that allows you to use a Samsung GALAXY Note 4 as the screen and CPU to drive the VR experience.

If you look closely at the image you can see the GEAR logo on the side of HMD.

If you click through the ad to go to the http://braintree.stackexchange.com/ page it does show the correct device.

Comment: And crumbs: only US residents are eligible? They could've made that clearer on the contest page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Restricted to US only is a common enough restriction that if it is not explicitly stated that it is open to non US the first thing I would do is click the Terms and Conditions link (and being US only is the first  sentenace in that link)

Comment: I hope this ad is disabled for non-US IP addresses then.

Comment: @Martijn you could reasonably come to the conclusion that they only want US customers.

Comment: @AdamEberbach: I imagine it's more just a matter of it being infeasible to ensure compliance with the lottery/promotion regulations of every jurisdiction on Earth. Whatever the reason may be, given that the majority of SO users are non-US based and hence ineligible to win a prize, *something* should change - possibly the addition of a small-text disclaimer on the ad itself.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I don't think that's reasonable at all.  Most people _never_ read the Terms of Conditions, regardless of nationality.

Comment: @Mac: *"majority of SO users are non-US "* is probably *not* true but I see your point.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian At least back in 2009 [_"the majority of SO users were non-US"_](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-come-from).

Comment: @Akori: you are right. Though the data shows that US provides more traffic than the other top 10 countries combined.

Comment: Yeah, that's not great; I'll see who I can get hold of

Comment: [According to Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com) that number's down to 26.7% from the US @J.F.Sebastian. Still the most, but not by much any more, and far less than the rest of the world. talking solely about geography then [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com/geo/countries?country=UK&undefined=&req=0.1970062288455665&start=16) has Europe at about the same as the US with India & China still doing well despite being significantly less than Alexa.... contd

Comment: ... contd It's not unreasonable to assume that with 3/4 of the readership outside the US and equal numbers in other locales that some adverts might cater for the rest of the world.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I based that assertion on the data obtained by the [2013 Stack Overflow User Survey](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/), which reported that roughly 27.8% of respondents were US-based. Possibly not the most accurate, unbiased or up-to-date data available, but the numbers Ben found seem to back it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this one! A fix is on the way and the campaign should be updated shortly.